# Javascript find the closest number in an array of objects and retrieve the object's key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, max

I have an array of objects(with `keys`: `name`, `quoteNumber`)and I would like to find the closest `quoteNumber` that is smaller than a given number then retrieve that object's name, I have consider using a for loop to remove the larger values, and get the max value from the remaining ones ,yet it might not be the best option given how large the dataset would be. Is this any other algorithm that is more efficient? Thanks!

```
const givenNum = 45
var array = [ 

    { name: "Sally",
      quoteNumber: 35},
    { name: "Jane",
      quoteNumber: 20},
    { name: "Edwin",
      quoteNumber: 55},
    { name: "Carrie",
      quoteNumber: 47}];

//'result:' Sally
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's unsorted, about the most efficient you can be is a single pass.

```js
function getHighestQuote(quotes, limit) {
  let winner = null;
  let winningQuote = null;
  for (let {name, quoteNumber} of quotes) {
    if (quoteNumber > limit)
      continue;
    if (winningQuote === null || winningQuote < quoteNumber) {
      winner = name;
      winningQuote = quoteNumber;
    }
  }
  return winner;
}
```

It's not quite as snazzy as a functional approach, but it's a single linear-time pass that only needs to allocate a few stack variables.

Comment: By the way, if you expect performance to matter, it's not a bad idea to benchmark with a representative data set. Here's a quick example (I don't know what your data actually looks like): https://jsbench.me/ebkm29r1xu/1

Comment: "only needs to allocate a few stack variables"  could be optimized by using `for (var {name, quoteNumber} ...` instead of `let` since it will reuse the variable reference instead of creating a new one. `var` isn't completely dead ;)

Comment: I believe modern JS engines will eliminate that difference (and I'd worry more about the `for..of` needing to generate code to deal with non-array deopts), but I haven't checked the assembly. Feel free to benchmark in your browser of choice if the difference may matter. :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with being semantically correct if you're not sure what the JS engine will do - especially if performance is a concern. Or do people really hate `var` that much?

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer. Although I like the succinctness of mine this is 100% the fastest way with a large dataset

Comment: Having played with the snazzy benchmark thing a bit. Using `for(let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++)` etc. seems a fair bit faster, unless I've done something wrong.

Comment: Yes, that makes some sense -- for...of iteration needs to deal with non-arrays and can be somewhat slower. It's hard to beat indexed iteration on plain arrays.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a large dataset, you want to avoid doing anything which either loops over the array more than once, or even attempts to sort it before looking. A simple aggregate operation will do this fine. Use `reduce`

```js
const givenNum = 45
var array = [ 

    { name: "Sally",
      quoteNumber: 35},
    { name: "Jane",
      quoteNumber: 20},
    { name: "Edwin",
      quoteNumber: 55},
    { name: "Carrie",
      quoteNumber: 47}];
      

const result = array.reduce ( (acc,item) => {
    const diff = givenNum - item.quoteNumber;
    if(item.quoteNumber < givenNum && diff < acc.diff)
       acc = {diff,  item}
    return acc;
},{ diff: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, item: null });

console.log(result.item);
```

Note also that if speed is *really* important avoid this solution too - it has extra method calls you won't have with with the simpler [loop solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66551463/219661). That will *always* be the fastest option.

Comment: Perfect use case for `.reduce()`. This would be my preferred solution

Comment: That reduce statement can be shorten to:
`const result = array.reduce((pv, cv) => cv.quoteNumber <= givenNum && cv.quoteNumber > (pv?.quoteNumber ?? 0) ? cv : pv, null)`

Comment: @andi2.2 It can indeed, but somewhat bizarrely on my browser that is slower than mine (https://jsbench.me/lekm2aluqw/1) whereas logically (to me at least) it looks like it should be quicker

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for your comment on my (now deleted) post. Looking at the benchmark thingy, if I set `quoteNumber: Math.random() * 100` to `quoteNumber: Math.random() * 10000` I get Foo_reduceFind2 as the quickest response with foo_filterSort at just 14.66% slower. If you set it to Math.random() * 100000 (to match the number of entries) Foo_reduceFind, Foo_reduceFind2 and foo_filterSort come out as joint fastest.

Comment: @Jamiec That was in Firefox. In Chrome Foo_reduceFind, Foo_reduceFind2 and foo_filterSort are all tied but foo_forLoop is much faster.

Comment: @Jamiec Apologies for spamming a bit, setting the test case to have 50000 as the limit and foo_filterSort is bad again.

Comment: Thank you! I applied this algorithm and it works perfectly!

Comment: @yhshj Take note of my final paragraph!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple one-liner that kicks out all elements with a larger quote-number, sorts the other elements and finally get's the first element(-> the closest one):

```
const closest_smaller = array.filter(a => a.quoteNumber <= givenNum).sort((a,b) => b.quoteNumber-a.quoteNumber)[0]
```

If the givenNum is smaller than every quoteNumber, this returns undefined.
if you want to have a fallback use:

```
const closest_smaller = array.filter(a => a.quoteNumber <= givenNum).sort((a,b) => b.quoteNumber-a.quoteNumber)[0] ?? 0
```

You also can use `find` instead of `filter`, i don't exactly know which one is faster:

```
const closest_smaller = array.sort((a,b) => b.quoteNumber-a.quoteNumber).find(a => a.quoteNumber <= givenNum) ?? 0
```

Comment: Question had the magic words "Large dataset" so you want to avoid amnything `O(nlogn)` like sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @Jeremy Roman's and @Jamiec's answers. I think this is a good bit faster unless I've done something stupid: https://jsbench.me/g0kmha8buo/1

```js
const array = [
  { name: "Sally",
    quoteNumber: 35},
  { name: "Jane",
    quoteNumber: 20},
  { name: "Velma",
    quoteNumber: 31},
  { name: "Edwin",
    quoteNumber: 55},
  { name: "Neva",
    quoteNumber: 30},
  { name: "Carrie",
    quoteNumber: 47},
  { name: "Arnold",
    quoteNumber: 29},
];

function closest_quote_less_than_or_equal_to(quotes, limit) {
  let winner = null;
  let winningQuote = 0;

  const limit_plus_one = limit + 1;

  for(let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    const quoteNumber = quotes[i].quoteNumber;
    if(((quoteNumber < limit_plus_one) * quoteNumber) > winningQuote) {
      winningQuote = quoteNumber;
      winner = quotes[i].name;
    }
  }

  return winner;
}

console.log(closest_quote_less_than_or_equal_to(array, 45));
console.log(closest_quote_less_than_or_equal_to(array, 30));
console.log(closest_quote_less_than_or_equal_to(array, 10));
```